# python pandas apply function group by group

Tags: python, function, pandas, apply

I have a pandas matrix df of the form:

```
user_id     time           url
4           20140502    'w.lejournal.fr/actualite/politique/sarkozy-terminator_1557749.html',
7           20140307    'w.lejournal.fr/palmares/palmares-immobilier/'
10          20140604    'w.lejournal.fr/actualite/societe/adeline-hazan-devient-la-nouvelle-controleuse-des-lieux-de-privation-de-liberte_1558176.html'
etc...
```

I want to use the groupby function to group by user, then to make some statistics of the words appearing in the urls of each user, for example, get how many times there is the world 'actualite' in a user urls.

For now, my code is:

```
def my_stat_function(temp_set):
    res = 0
    for (u,t) in temp_set:
        if 'actualite' in u and t > 20140101:
            res += 1
    return res

group_user = df.groupby('user_id')
output_list = []
for (i,group) in group_user:
    dfg = pandas.DataFrame(group)
    temp_set = [tuple(x) for x in dfg[['url','time']].values]
    temp_var = my_stat_function(temp_set)
    output_list.append([i]+[temp_var])
outputDf = pandas.DataFrame(data = output_list, columns = ['user_id','stat'])
```

My question is: can I avoid to iterate group by group to apply my_stat_function, and is there exist something faster, maybe applying the function apply? I would really like something more "pandas-ish' and faster.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can apply functions to groups: `df.groupby('user_id').apply(my_stat_function)` or similar, have you tried this?

Comment: Thank you for your help, my problem is that I don't know how to define my_stat_function in order to apply it like this, because I need the full data of each group, It is not a row by row execution. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: You'd have to post your stat function and your requirements so that we can better understand your needs

Comment: for example: my_stat_function take in argument the list of tuples (time,url) for a given user, and count the occurences of the word 'actualite' in the urls of the list which date is later than 20140101. So to get the result for each user, my_stat_function needs all the content of the 'temp_set' variable, i.e., It can not be applied row by row nor columns by columns on dfg[['url','time']].

Comment: You could groupby user and apply the function,  you'd have to rewrite your function though

Comment: Ok thank you a lot, but I don't see how to define my_stat_function. What will it take in argument?

Comment: A dataframe grouped on your user, please edit your question with code and expected output

Comment: I edited my question as you suggested.

Comment: But I still don't see how to define my_stat_functon for a dataframe grouped. Could someone give me a hint of how to start please?